# Problem in removing and showing row in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am having a problem in my code of hiding and displaying the row again but it isn't working. when i comment the code of 2nd loop then it woks perfectly fine but when i add 2nd loop then again trouble. Here is my code.

```
<script>


    $("#btnClick").click(function(){

        $("form input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").each(
        function(){
                var checkBoxID = $(this).attr('id');

                //alert("checkBoxID"+" "+checkBoxID);
                $("table td").each(function(){

                    if(checkBoxID==$(this).attr('id')){
                    //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });
        });

        $("form input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(
        function(){
                var checkBoxID = $(this).attr('id');

                //alert("checkBoxID"+" "+checkBoxID);
                $("table td").each(function(){

                    if(checkBoxID==$(this).attr('id')){
                    //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may use shorter definisions: $( 'form :checkbox:not(:checked)' ) and jQuery( 'form :checkbox:checked' ) instead of $("form input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)") and $("form input[type=checkbox][checked]") respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

> $("form
>   input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(

with

> $("form
>   input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(

Comment: Thanks Phelios it worked :). Sorry for late reply. Can you please tell me the difference between two lines.

Comment: `[checked]` vs `:checked`. :checked is one word in jquery, so [checked] is actually invalid. [] is used in attribute search.

Answer (score 0):

What is actually happening is that in the $.each loops, when you refer to $(this) it is actually examining the td, since you are using $("table td").

Actually... looking a second time it seems that you are probably using the same ID for the checkbox and the td to hide it?

**The Problem:** replace the initial each function with this:

```
$("form input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").each(//..
```

.

```
$("#btnClick").click( function(){ 
   $("form input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").each( function(){ 
     var checkBoxID = $(this).attr('id'); 
     //alert("checkBoxID"+" "+checkBoxID); 
     $("table td").each(function(){ 
        if(checkBoxID==$(this).attr('id')){ 
          //alert($(this).attr('id')); 
          $(this).hide(); 
        } 
     }); 
   }); 
   $("form input[type=checkbox][checked]").each( function(){ 
      var checkBoxID = $(this).attr('id'); 
      //alert("checkBoxID"+" "+checkBoxID); 
      $("table td").each(function(){ 
         if(checkBoxID==$(this).attr('id')){ 
            //alert($(this).attr('id')); 
            $(this).show(); 
          }  
      }); 
    }); 
});
```